# Definition and properties of "real weighted projective spaces"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, group-actions, orbifolds

I've seen a lot of literature on Complex weighted projective spaces (sometimes defined in a flavour of algebraic geometry) which can be obtained as the orbit spaces of the action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ defined by $$\lambda \cdot (z_0,\ldots, z_n):=(\lambda^{a_0}z_0,\ldots,\lambda^{a_n}z_n),$$ where $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)\subset\mathbb{N}^{n+1}$.

I imagine that we can define the same action of $\mathbb{R}^*$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ and look at the orbit space that what would be called a "real weighted projective space".

Is something known about these spaces, for example if they are compact and if they are orbifolds? Does anyone can give me a reference? I'll be very pleased, thanks!

Comment: There is nothing special about $\mathbb C$ in the definition; you can just as well study $k^*$ acting on $k^{n+1} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ for any field $k$. Again, the proof of compactness should carry through with no changes. As for the orbifold question: I don't think so. They are never described as stacks in the AG literature (that I've seen), just singular varieties.

Comment: Thanks, sir. Do you know any place to read the proof of compactness?

Comment: Have you not come across a proof of compactness of complex weighted projective spaces? If so, I would assume it's because it's basically the same proof as for ordinary projective space.